# Is there way to leave only unique tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Is there way to leave only unique tabs in Firefox? That means, I'd like to close all the tabs with duplicate URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its documentation, the add-on [Closy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/closy/) has features such as:

- Close all blank/duplicate tabs.
- Close all tabs to the left/right.
- Close all tabs from a certain host.
- Close all tabs with certain text in source/title.